# How to convert MutableList to RequestBody?

Tags: android, kotlin

Try to convert MutableList to RequestBody. However, there is an error and the conversion does not work. Also, we want to initialize requestHashMap.

```
private suspend fun postWriting() {
        var content = writing_writing_edit.toString()
        var hashtags: MutableList<String> = viewModel.hashtags(content)
        var requestHashMap:HashMap<String, RequestBody>

        if(getImageFile != null && content != null){

            when(sound){
                true -> requestHashMap["sound"] = file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                false -> requestHashMap["sound"] = getAudioFile!!.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                false -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"오디오 파일이 필요합니다",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    return
                }
            }
            requestHashMap["content"] = content.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            requestHashMap["hashtag"] = hashtags.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())

        }
        viewModel.writing(requestHashMap)
        changeView()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Builder first to change string to RequestBody. This is similar function :

```
public fun getFormDataRequest(stringList: List<String>) : RequestBody {
        val requestBody : RequestBody =  MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("NewCar1", stringList.get(0))
            .addFormDataPart("NewCar2", stringList.get(1))
            .build()

        return requestBody
    }
```